# Python 3 find specific metacharacters or letters in user input

Tags: python-3.x, input, character, match

I am trying to make a folder creator script which works great, however when you type in ":" for example without quotes as the folder name it does some strange things. I wrote the code below to try to handle any characters such as those when someone tries to name a folder with them. Code below seems to work good, but if and only if one of the characters in the extensions variable appears as the very first character of the name will it detect it and kick off the exception message. Also what is the best way to handle blank/empty input, is there a way to include that into the below while loop or should there be a seperate while loop to handle the blank input if there is any?

If someone types in hello: it will not kick off the message and tries to proceed but causing it to not make the folder or if it does naming them numbers such as 1,2 etc.

I apologize in advanced if there is already a post on this out there, but I've been looking everywhere for a resolution to this and have been testing different ways to resolve before coming here and have tried a few suggestions but does not seem to detect the characters anywhere in the input but only the first character. Maybe I could use regex and use a custom set to specify those characters but not sure how to set that up. Thanks

```
counter = 0
extensions = (":","?","<",">","|","/","\\") # list of characters that cannot be used for folder names 
while True:
    try:
        folder_name = input("Name of the folder you want. ")
        if folder_name in extensions: # checks the user input to see if any characters match the extensions variable.
            break 
        else:
            raise Exception
    except Exception as e:
        print("You can not have any of these characters in the folder name. ")
        time.sleep(3.5)
        cls()
```

Comment: This is only a piece of the code, not the entire folder creator script, the rest of the code works good but having issues with this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if folder_name in extensions:` does not check what your comment suggests. Try matching a regular expression instead.

Your exception-based flow isn't Pythonic. Why not initialize `folder_name` to something invalid and loop while it's still invalid?

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'[:?<>|/\\]')
folder_name = ''
while not folder_name or pattern.search(folder_name) is not None:
    folder_name = input("Name of the folder you want. ")
```

`not folder_name` further checks that `folder_name` is not empty.

Comment: I've tried this suggestion with no luck. I'm not sure if I'm implementing it wrong or what but basically when I run the program with this code it ask for the name of the folder and still will not throw an error if it detects the regular expression defined in "pattern" and allows any text to go through. Below is the change I added from your suggestion.

Comment: counter = 0
    # Create some exception handling to deal with bad input, such as blank input, ":" characters in folder names etc.

    pattern = re.compile(r':?<>|/\\')
    folder_name = ''
    while not folder_name or pattern.search(folder_name) is not None:
        folder_name = input("Name of the folder you want. ")

Comment: @Travy641 Sorry, I forgot the brackets to indicate the character group.

Answer (score 0):

In your code,  "if folder_name in extensions:" line is problematic, since it is checking if given folder name is in the list extensions. You need

```
for a_character in extensions:
    if a_character is in folder_name:
...
```

Here is another way of doing it

```
def check_folder_name(input_name):
    # create a set that has all values to exclude
    exclude = set(':"%/<>^|?\\')
    # check if two sets share any elements
    if set(input_name) & exclude:
        print('Please remove the following characters from the folder name')
        print(list(set(input_name) & exclude))
        return False
    else:
        return True


check_folder_name('sample_correct_folder_name')
>True

check_folder_name('sample:problematic%folder^name')
>Please remove the following characters from the folder name
>[':', '%', '^']
```